# Map System.Drawing.Image to proper PdfName.COLORSPACE and PdfName.FILTER in iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I'm using iTextSharp to update an image object in a PDF with a modified System.Drawing.Image. How do I properly set the PdfName.COLORSPACE and PdfName.FILTER based on the System.Drawing.Image? I'm not sure which System.Drawing.Image properties can be used for the mappings.

```
private void SetImageData(PdfImageObject pdfImage, System.Drawing.Image image, byte[] imageData)
{
    PRStream imgStream = (PRStream)pdfImage.GetDictionary();
    imgStream.Clear();
    imgStream.SetData(imageData, false, PRStream.NO_COMPRESSION);
    imgStream.Put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
    imgStream.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE);
    imgStream.Put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(image.Width));
    imgStream.Put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(image.Height));
    imgStream.Put(PdfName.LENGTH, new PdfNumber(imageData.LongLength));

    // Not sure how to properly set these entries based on the image properties
    imgStream.Put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, 8);
    imgStream.Put(PdfName.COLORSPACE, PdfName.DEVICERGB);
    imgStream.Put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.DCTDECODE);
}
```

Comment: If you want to cheat, just add the image to a PDF normally, inspect those properties and use them here.

Comment: Cheating sounds like a good idea. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the advice of Chris Haas and cheated by writing the System.Drawing.Image to a temporary PDF and then read it back out as a PdfImageObject.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
    {
        using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc))
        {
            doc.Open();

            iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(drawingImage, drawingImage.RawFormat);
            image.SimplifyColorspace();

            doc.Add(image);
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
    ... code that opens the mem stream with PdfReader and retrieves the image as PdfImageObj...
}
```

That worked but seemed like allot of side stepping for a cheat. I stepped through the code in the call to `doc.Add(image)` and found that eventually a PdfImage object was created from the iTextSharp.text.Image object and the PdfImage object contained all the dictionary entries that I needed. So I decided to cut some corners on the original cheat and come up with this as my final solution:

```
private void SetImageData(PdfImageObject pdfImageObj, byte[] imageData)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageData);
    image.SimplifyColorSpace();

    PdfImage tempPdfImage = new PdfImage(image, "TempImg", null);

    PRStream imgStream = (PRStream)pdfImageObj.GetDictionary();
    imgStream.Clear();
    imgStream.SetDataRaw(imageData);
    imgStream.Merge(tempPdfImage);
}
```